# Cheerio returning empty arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I tried scraping with cheerio and everything was working. Then I tried to make the scraped links into working links by adding in the base url to the links, but suddenly this error showed up.

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'links' before initialization
```

I checked if I was getting the data from the site and axios side is working. But for some reason, cheerio stopped working. When I tried logging it gave me an empty array of elements like this,

```
LoadedCheerio(136) [Element, Element, Element, Element, Element]
```

I don't understand why. I need help to figure out about the problem.

Here's my code:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import * as cheerio from 'cheerio';

const baseUrl = 'https://gogoanime.tel/anime-list.html';

axios.get(baseUrl).then(res => {
    const html = res.data;
    const $ =  cheerio.load(html);
    const list = $('.listing a');
    const links = list.each(function (i, el)  {
        $(el).attr('href');
    });
   
});
```

Comment: Neither of your issues are reproduced by this code, which works fine for me. Please share a [mcve]. The log isn't an empty array. Thanks.